# QuickBlox retrieve content with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, quickblox, mbaas

I've been trying to retrieve contents from Quickblox, unfortunately nothing is showing.

Here is code sample

```
    let page = QBGeneralResponsePage(currentPage: 1, perPage: 10)
QBRequest.blobsForPage(page, successBlock: { (response :QBResponse,
    page, blobs:[QBCBlob]?) -> Void in
    print(blobs)
    }) { (response :QBResponse) -> Void in
        print(response.error?.description)
}
```

It's showing :

{

```
2016-02-22 16:34:23.753 cloudkit[27461:732075] [QBCore] Response object: {
    "current_page" = 1;
    items =     (
    );
    "per_page" = 10;
    "total_entries" = 0;
}
```

}

I need help!!!

Comment: Its clearly says there is 0 entries. Are you sure that there are some?

Comment: Actually I do have imported all my data from Parse, but is not showing

Comment: Hi! Please write us http://assist.quickblox.com If problem is related to Parse-Quickblox migration, we are happy to help you. Thanks!